# C - alternating Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, conways-game-of-life

I've been struggling to understand how to work with pointers generally. I have in the example below a little sketch of an update function (updateGrid) for Game of life. The idea is to update the state of all cells in the grid between true and false (as you might know).
However, I'm supposed to use pointers in order to alternate between the 'previous' and 'new' state of the grid. But I don't seem to figure out how to implement this concept of alternating pointers without making a copy of the current cells grid. Any idea?

By the way, my code below works so far just fine.

```
// ---------- Global Variables ----------

bool cells[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
bool cells_next[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

bool (*ptr)[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
bool (*ptr_next)[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

ptr = &cells;
ptr_next = &cells_next;

// ---------- update state ----------

void updateState() {
    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_SIZE; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < MAX_SIZE; ++col) {
            if (((*ptr)[row][col]) == 1) {
                if ((numAliveNeighbors(row, col) < 2)
                || (numAliveNeighbors(row, col) > 3)) {
                    (*ptr_next)[row][col] = 0;
                } else {
                    (*ptr_next)[row][col] = 1;
                }
            } else if (((*ptr)[row][col]) == 0) {
                if (numAliveNeighbors(row, col) == 3) {
                    (*ptr_next)[row][col] = 1;
                } else {
                    (*ptr_next)[row][col] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_SIZE; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < MAX_SIZE; ++col) {
            (*ptr)[row][col] = (*ptr_next)[row][col];
            (*ptr_next)[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
```

PS: My problem explanation may seem a little bumpy so don't hesitate for further infos.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does *"alternating pointers"* mean?

Comment: Hint: after "updating", the new state is written into `cells_next`, based on the existing `cells` content. What needs to happen in the next generation? You would want to write the new state, based on what's currently... in `cells_next`. Correct? Can you think of an existing array where we could write that data, where the existing contents are no longer relevant? (Hint: it's the only other array mentioned in this comment.)

Comment: Now, consider: suppose you had two pointers, `ptr` that is intended to point at the array for the current state, and `ptr_next` that is intended to point at the array for the next state. In order to make `cells_next` be the array used for the current state, how would you change `ptr`? How would you change `ptr_next` so that it points at an appropriate array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note these remarks:

- You should use pointer to rows instead of pointers to 2D arrays.
- You can *alternate* the pointers by swapping the via a temporary variable.

The code implements [John Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)'s famous Game of Life generations. `ptr` points to the current board and `ptr_next` points to the next generation. `update()` computes the new board applying the rules for cell death and birth. When the new board has been fully updated, the pointers are swapped, so `ptr` now points to the new board. This is faster than copying the full board from `cells_next` to `cells`.

Here is a modified version:

```
// ---------- Global Variables ----------

bool cells[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
bool cells_next[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

bool (*ptr)[MAX_SIZE] = cells;
bool (*ptr_next)[MAX_SIZE] = cells_next;

// ---------- update state ----------

void updateState() {
    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_SIZE; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < MAX_SIZE; ++col) {
            if (ptr[row][col]) {
                if ((numAliveNeighbors(row, col) < 2)
                ||  (numAliveNeighbors(row, col) > 3)) {
                    ptr_next[row][col] = 0;
                } else {
                    ptr_next[row][col] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (numAliveNeighbors(row, col) == 3) {
                    ptr_next[row][col] = 1;
                } else {
                    ptr_next[row][col] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // swap the pointers
    bool (*tmp)[MAX_SIZE] = ptr;
    ptr = ptr_next;
    ptr_next = tmp;
}
```

Note that `numAliveNeighbors` should probably take `ptr` as an argument instead of implicitly via a global variable.

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain the underlying logic as well - i.e., *why* "swap" the pointers, and what the *purpose* of the pointers is.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: good point. Answer amended.